# Problem updating from 21.10 to 22.04

Tags: upgrade

I am currently running 21.10. So I run the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease
Get:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease [1,811 B]                                                                                                   
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease                                                                                                                           
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease                                                                                                     
Hit:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease                                                              
Hit:6 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease             
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease   
Get:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages [1,098 B]
Fetched 2,909 B in 0s (6,063 B/s)   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.

$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  teamviewer:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
teamviewer/stable 15.31.5 i386 [upgradable from: 12.0.258841]
```

I cannot upgrade from version 12 of Teamviewer, as my license does not support it. When I run the Software Updater, it gives me the option to upgrade to 22.04 LTS. But when I click on the 'Upgrade' button, the software updater closes without giving any sort of indication as to why. I'm guessing that it has something to do with having an old version of Teamviewer, but I don't know what to do from here. Thoughts? TIA.

Comment: Remove teamviewer and then install it post-upgrade?  If that doesn't work, then you're stuck without the ability to use TeamViewer if you don't have a license for it anymore.

Comment: The *release-upgrade* process requires no packages in the queue for upgrade; your paste shows "*1 not upgraded*".  I agree 100% with what Thomas said.

Comment: If dependencies of teamviewer 12 allow it, you can install it after the upgrade again. If not try to ignore missing dependencies while installing Teamviewer 12. Another option would be to create a Ubuntu 20.04 chroot  in your new ubuntu 22.04 and try running teamviewer 12 inside it.